# Calling functions from a std::map

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, c++14

I'm trying to construct `Object` that will serve as a handler for my functions. To explain why, I'll use this to scan for user input, check the map for a match. If a match is found, I will call the function and copy the rest of the *user-inputted* line to the function;

```
class Object
{
public:
    Object(std::map<std::string, void(*)(const std::string&)> MAP)
        {/*...code...*/};
};
```

Quick example code:

```
class Main
{
public:
    void testFunc(const std::string& A)
    {

    }

    void construct()
    {
        Object{
            std::map<std::string, void(*)(const std::string&)> {
                {"exit", [](const std::string &A){ exit(1); }},
                //{"test1", (void(Main::*)(const std::string&))&testFunc},
                //{"test2", [](const std::string &A){ testFunc(A); }},
                //{"test3", [this](const std::string &A){ testFunc(A); }},
                {"NULL", NULL}
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Neither of the commented lines worked, creating different errors, but the other lines succeeded and there are no runtime errors (Well, NULL would be, but I'm handling that).

My question is, Am I imagining the mechanics of this properly, if not, should I save just the pointers and cast to functions later? Is it possible to save a reference and call functions inside a object that is defined only inside the class scope (calls would be made from inside the class too)?

A lot of questions.. I know. But I've never seen this done like this before.. so I guess there might be a good reason.

Because I didn't specify the errors, [here is a link](https://ideone.com/1DkT8N);

Comment: Consider references and `std::function`

Comment: `testFunc`'s type is `void(Main::*)(std::string const&)`, not `void(*)(std::string const&)` – big difference.

Comment: If you can declare `testFunc` as `static` it will eliminate the error.

Comment: @ildjarn Opps, that was a rewrite mistake, fixed.

Comment: @areuz : I'm not sure what you're saying you fixed...

Comment: @ildjarn I fixed it in the question - it still creates errors, that was not really the point. But I think Mark Ransom and Barry have great solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-`static` member functions are different from non-member functions in that they take an extra implicit argument - the class instance. `Main::testFunc` requires two arguments: a `Main` and a `std::string const&`. But your interface only allows for a single argument. The only way to make this work is to create a global `Main*` that the function would reference - which is a terribly brittle design.

Instead, you could make your interface more generic by using `std::function<void(std::string const&)>`. This is *any* callable that takes a `std::string const&`, instead of just a pointer to a function. This would allow you to write your last version:

```
{"test3", [this](const std::string &A){ testFunc(A); }},
```

and is probably your best bet.

Comment: *"Member functions are different from non-member functions in that they take an extra implicit argument"* Non-static member functions that is. (Sry for being pedantic.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen This is C++. There is pedantic and there is wrong.

Comment: Thank you :) Still getting used to C++.
Looks like it solves the problem for all my functions and I like that It uses Lambda. That way it gives me the *option* to use the passed argument else it goes out of scope.